# Сортировка MySQL по floating point числу

Tags: mysql, php, сортировка, sql

Тут понадобилась случайная выборка из таблицы в MySQL. Столкнулся с таким рабочим, но черепашьим решением как `SELECT ...... FROM.....ORDER BY RAND()`. Решил для оптимизации запроса `floating point` число, генерируемое `RAND()`, сгенерить на php. Но вот беда: не пойму я как это работает. Понимаю когда сортировка по имени, псевдониму, позиции столбца. В общем тому кто объяснит спасибо и лайк разумеется.

Comment: вам нужна одна строчка ?

Answer (score 2):

Там не вещественное число подставляется, а скорее всего парсер запроса MySQL видя конструкцию ORDER BY RAND() понимает что нужно достать случайную запись, выполняет свой алгоритм. Точное описание процесса надо гуглить, быстро не получилось найти инфы, позже попробую ещё поискать.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...... FROM.....ORDER BY RAND()
```

действительно работает медленно. Кстати, из-за `RAND()` в этом контексте. Когда-то давно читал об альтернативных решениях, думаю сейчас мало что изменилось.

Варианты, которые я использовал:

1. Получить данные в массив PHP и сделать `shuffle()`;
2. Вытащить id нужных записей, перемешать/обрезать их и сделать запрос на получение самих записей с использованием `'WHERE id IN (8, 2, 5, 16, 3, 4...)'`

Второй вариант удобен при сложном наборе условий в `WHERE`